# Как убрать пробел в конце строки?

Tags: javascript, строки

Мне нужно чтобы переменная `text` выдавала в конце строку:

```
'22 32 4242 2 242 424 2 2'
```

а она выдает такую же, но с пробелом в конце:

```
'22 32 4242 2 242 424 2 2 '
```

пожалуйста подскажите как можно обойти эту неприятную ситуацию.

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  let tes = text.split('');
  let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    text ='' ;
  for(let p = 0;p < tes.length; p++){
      for(let i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
      if(tes[p].toLowerCase() === arr[i].toLowerCase()){
        text = `${text}${i+1} `;
      }            
      }
    }
  return text;
}
console.log('::' + alphabetPosition('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet') + '::')
console.log('::' + alphabetPosition('consectetur adipiscing elit') + '::')
```

Comment: удалите просто в ней этот пробел ```text = `${text}${i+1}`;```

Comment: тогда будет так ```'22324242224242422' ``` этот пробел как бы необходим, но вот то что он вылазиет в конце не приятность,которая все ломает

Comment: вы в цикле меняете значение?

Comment: суть той программы в том  что она заменяет буквы на их позиции в англ алфавите и выдает то же предложение,но цифрами(знаки препинания не учитываются)

Comment: `return text.trim()` и все, не?

Answer (score 2):

Для того что бы убрать лишний пробел **только в конце строки** можно воспользоваться новым методом [trimEnd()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd):

```js
const string = "22 32 4242 2 242 424 2 2 "

const result = string.trimEnd()

console.log(result)
// "22 32 4242 2 242 424 2 2"
```

или же задействовать обычный [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), который очистит строку от пробелов **с двух сторон** (в начале и конце):

```js
const string = " 22 32 4242 2 242 424 2 2 "

const result = string.trim()

console.log(result)
// "22 32 4242 2 242 424 2 2"
```

Т.е в Вашем случае достаточно:

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  // ... код функции
  return text.trimEnd()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй `join` вместо конкатенации руками.

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

  return text.split("").flatMap(ch => {
    var i = arr.indexOf(ch.toLowerCase())
    return i === -1 ? [] : i
  }).join(" ")
}

console.log('::' + alphabetPosition('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet') + '::')
console.log('::' + alphabetPosition('consectetur adipiscing elit') + '::')
```